# DllImport is not found C++

Tags: dllimport

I am having trouble with using the `DllImport` function!

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

It will show me no attribute when run. I am using a Windows Form with C++. And I am really noob with WindowsForms.

```
namespace Projekt3{

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;



public ref class next : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);


public:

    next(void)
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Konstruktorcode hier hinzufügen.
        //
    }
public: enum fsmodifiers
{

    NOMOD = 0x0000,
    ALT = 0x0001,
    CTRL = 0x0002,
    SHIFT = 0x0004,
    WIN = 0x0008,

};
```

Comment: try adding `DllImportAttribute`. Also in C++/CLI, you can call the Win32 API directly!

Comment: Didn't work for me. Thank you for the fast answer tho.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly well, in so far as we can see it. For example, this program

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern int MessageBox(System::IntPtr hwnd, System::String^ text, System::String^ caption, 
    unsigned int uType);

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    MessageBox((System::IntPtr)0, "foo", "bar", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

produces the expected message box.

It is very much worth pointing out that using p/invoke from C++/CLI seems like a very pointless exercise. You can link to unmanaged code directly. It would be much more natural for this C++/CLI program to be written like so:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "foo", "bar", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```